# Object required of a parameter in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I'm new to VBScript, and I have a function that allows me to pull synchronizing preferences from a preferences file, and it looks like this:

```
Function IsSync(SyncFolder)
    If FS.FileExists(PrefFilePath) Then
        Set objFile = FS.OpenTextFile(PrefFilePath, 1)
        PrefLine = "start"
        Do Until Prefline.Substring(0, SyncFolder.Length) = SyncFolder
            PrefLine = objFile.Readline
        Loop

        If PrefLine.Substring(PrefLine.Length - 6) = "nosync" Then
            IsSync = False
        Else
            IsSync = True
        End If
    Else
        IsSync = True
    End If
End Function
```

But when I try to run it, Windows throws me an error of "Object required: SyncFolder" whenever it gets to this function. Why is this? SyncFolder is just a parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VBScript, every variable has not some built-in methods. And if a variable has a property or method this means it's an Object. But your parameter does not seems like an object, this is why the error occurred. 
So, there is no built-in methods such as *SubString* or another for the string variables in the VBScript.

1. Use [Len](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_len.asp) function to get length of string instead of
   `.Length`.
2. Use [Mid](http://www3.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_mid.asp), [Left](http://www3.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_left.asp) or [Right](http://www3.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_right.asp) functions which one if you need to istead of `.SubString`.

I guess you need to use *-with order-* **Len**, **Left** and **Right** functions in this case.

Consider this :

```
Function IsSync(SyncFolder)
    If FS.FileExists(PrefFilePath) Then
        Set objFile = FS.OpenTextFile(PrefFilePath, 1)
        PrefLine = "start"
        Do Until Left(Prefline, Len(SyncFolder)) = SyncFolder 'starts with SyncFolder
            PrefLine = objFile.Readline
        Loop

        If Right(PrefLine, 5) = "nosync" Then 'ends with "nosync"
            IsSync = False
        Else
            IsSync = True
        End If
    Else
        IsSync = True
    End If
End Function
```